# Connecting Kinect on USB 1.0

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to connect Kinect on USB 1.0 port, but it is not working. Is it possible to use Kinect on USB 1.0.

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51660/connecting-kinect-on-usb-1.0/) by [ama](https://answers.ros.org/users/3049/ama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2013-01-08**:
It's quite possible that the kinect doesn't work on USB 1.0, as I know there are often issues with USB 3.0. Sometimes the issue is that the USB port does not supply power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At full bandwidth, USB 1 can do 12Mbps. There is no way a kinect can run with this limited bandwidth.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4